# String & objects in Java

Tags: java, string, object

```
String a = "Hello";
String b = new String("Hello World");
```

Can someone please tell me how many objects are created and elaborate.

Thank you.

Comment: I am pretty sure this one has been asked a few times here already.

Answer (score 0):

> `String greeting = "Hello world!";`
>   In this case, **"Hello world!"** is a
>   string literal—a series of characters in your code that is enclosed in
>   double quotes. Whenever it encounters a string literal in your code,
>   the compiler creates a `String` object with its value—in this case,
>   **Hello world!**.

```
String a = "Hello"; // 1 object
String b = new String("Hello World"); 
// 1 object with new String(), 
// 1 object with "Hello World"
```

in total you created 3 objecs.

Comment: There are more than just 3 objects: String pool (1 object), `String.class` (1 object), the backing `char[]` for each `String` (since an array in Java is an object, 3 more objects), and on...